# SHINY R reading different versions of excel files based on user selections

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I have a shiny app, that reads in files that are uploaded by a user
Different people have different versions of excel. So if a user is using excel 2007 or excel 2010 we use one section of code. If they upload it in excel 2003 we use a different library to read the file. The user specifies in the form which version of excel they have

The function to do this is below

```
get_data <- function(strFilePath, storageType) {

  if (is.null(strFilePath))
    return(NULL)

  if (storagetType == 'xls2010' || storagetType == 'xls2007'){
      df <- openxlsx:read.xlsx(strFilePath,sheet = 1)
  }
  else if (storagetType == 'xls2003'){
    df <- XLConnect:readWorksheetFromFile(strFilePath)
  } 

  return(df)
}
```

To implement this in shiny, i have two widgets. A `fileInput` and a `selectInput`. The user selects which version of excel they are running and then selects the file which then is read in by the `function get_data`. I suspect its because I'm not utilizing the reactivity correctly. When i run the app and upload the file i get the error message

> Error: object 'storagetType' not found

```
# Global.R
storage_types <- c(
  "Excel 2010" = "xls2010",
  "Excel 2007" = "xls2007",
  "Excel 2003" = "xls2003"
)

# UI.R
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
 navbarPage("Navbar!",
             # Tab contains all the information to upload a file
             tabPanel("Upload Data",
                      # Side Panel with Options
                      fluidRow(
                        column(4, wellPanel(
                          id = "leftPanel",
                          div(
                            id = "Header",
                            h3("Options", align = "center"),
                            tags$hr()
                            ),

                          div(
                        selectInput("xlsversion", "2.  Select your Excel version", storage_types),
                        fileInput(inputId = 'file1',label =  '3.  Choose An Excel File'), 
                        )
)))))))

# Server.R

server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
   # When the Browser to the file location gets updated  
    upload_data <- reactive({
      inFile <- input$file1
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
      get_data(inFile$datapath, input$xlsversion)
})

})
```

Comment: its typo? `storageType` is not the same `storagetType` in your get_data  function

Comment: For what you need `selectInput("xlsversion",`? Why not simply check if inFile$name ended on xlsx or xls .. (others to error and it protect your from crash)

Comment: Hi @Batanichek , yes, the typo appears to be the issue. That's a much better idea if I parse the file name please add it as an answer and il mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need `selectInput` simply parse name of file.

Also some typo fixed

```
 library(shiny)

get_data <- function(strFilePath, storageType) {

  if (is.null(strFilePath))
    return(NULL)

  file_ext=substring(storageType,nchar(storageType)-3)
  if (file_ext == 'xlsx' ){
    df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(strFilePath,sheet = 1)
  }
  else if (file_ext == '.xls'){
    df <- XLConnect::readWorksheetFromFile(strFilePath,sheet=1)
  } else{
    return(data.frame("Bad file format"))
  }

  return(df)
}
# UI.R
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Navbar!",
             # Tab contains all the information to upload a file
             tabPanel("Upload Data",
                      # Side Panel with Options
                      fluidRow(
                        column(4, wellPanel(
                          id = "leftPanel",
                          div(
                            id = "Header",
                            h3("Options", align = "center"),
                            tags$hr()
                          ),

                          div(
                           fileInput(inputId = 'file1',label =  '3.  Choose An Excel File') 
                          )
                        ))),
                      dataTableOutput("result")))))

# Server.R

server <- function(input, output) {
    # When the Browser to the file location gets updated  
    upload_data <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$file1))
        return(NULL)
      get_data(input$file1$datapath, input$file1$name)
    })
    output$result=renderDataTable({
      upload_data()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```